# Creating a roman numeral translator as a service in Maven/Netbeans

Tags: java, web-services, maven, netbeans, glassfish

I'm trying to basically create a roman numeral translator and place it up onto Maven following some tutorials from my lecturer, problem is the tutorials aren't very informative. I have the code for the translator and it builds and the server runs up just fine, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do the get requests or post requests or where to even place them in the code. I'm getting a bit fed up so I thought I would ask here about how its done. First time really posting here so hopefully I didn't do anything wrong, my code for the translator is below. And I'm 100% sure my web file and pom file is done.

```
package com.mycompany.roman;


import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
/**
 *
 * @author Alex Wong
 */
@Path("roman")
@Produces("application/json")
public class RomanArabicConverter {


    //    Checks whether the entered Arabic numeral is valid

public boolean isValidArabic(int x) {
    String num = String.valueOf(x);

   //      Checks each character if it is a digit.

    for (int k = 0; k < num.length(); k++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(num.charAt(k)) == false) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //  Checking if the number is bigger than 3999 or smaller than 1
    if (x > 3999 ||x < 1) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


//    Checks whether the entered Roman numeral is valid

public boolean isValidRoman(String num) {

//    Checks each character if it is one of I, V, , L, C, D, M (Roman 
characters)

for (int k = 0; k < num.length(); k++) {
    if (num.charAt(k) != 'I' &&

            num.charAt(k) != 'V' &&

            num.charAt(k) != 'X' &&

            num.charAt(k) != 'L' &&

            num.charAt(k) != 'C' &&

            num.charAt(k) != 'D' &&

            num.charAt(k) != 'M') {

        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}

 //   Returns a string containing the entered Arabic numeral in Roman 
numeral form.
public String toRoman(int num) {

if (isValidArabic(num)) {  //      Checking if the number is a valid Arabic number

    String Roman = ""; //      This will be our result string.

    //    Declare and Initiate our Arrays
    String onesArray[] = {"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX"};
    String tensArray[] = {"X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC"};
    String hundredsArray[] = {"C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM"};

    //    Get the ones in the number
    int ones = num % 10;

    //    Get the tens
    num = (num - ones) / 10;
    int tens = num % 10;

    //    Get the hundreds
    num = (num - tens) / 10;
    int hundreds = num % 10;

    //    Get and write the thousands in the number to our string
    num = (num - hundreds) / 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        Roman += "M";
    }

    //    Write the hundreds
    if (hundreds >= 1) {
        Roman += hundredsArray[hundreds - 1];
    }

    //    Write the tens
    if (tens >= 1) {
        Roman += tensArray[tens - 1];
    }

    //    And finally, write the ones
    if (ones >= 1) {
        Roman += onesArray[ones - 1];
    }

    //    Return our string.
    return String.valueOf(Roman);

}else{
return null; //     If the number isn't a valid Arabic number, return null.
}
}
  //      Returns a string containing the entered Roman numeral in Arabic 
numeral form.
public String toArabic(String s) {

    if (isValidRoman(s)) { //      Check if the number is a valid Roman Number

        int Arabic = 0; //    This will be our result.
        int last_digit = 0;
        int current_digit = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            if (s.charAt(i) == 'I') {
                current_digit = 1;
            }
            if (s.charAt(i) == 'V') {
                current_digit = 5;
            }
            if (s.charAt(i) == 'X') {
                current_digit = 10;
            }
            if (s.charAt(i) == 'L') {
                current_digit = 50;
            }
            if (s.charAt(i) == 'C') {
                current_digit = 100;
            }
            if (s.charAt(i) == 'D') {
                current_digit = 500;
            }
            if (s.charAt(i) == 'M') {
                current_digit = 1000;
            }

            if (last_digit < current_digit && last_digit != 0) {
                current_digit -= last_digit;
                Arabic -= last_digit;
                Arabic += current_digit;
                last_digit = current_digit;
                current_digit = 0;
            } else {
                last_digit = current_digit;
                Arabic += current_digit;
                current_digit = 0;
            }
        }

        //    Return our string.
        return String.valueOf(Arabic);

    }else{
    return null;        //    Return null if the number entered is not a proper roman number.
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Just to add a further comment, I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to use cUrl for this. But again, not sure how to implement it into this code.

Comment: Your roman numeral conversion code is probably irrelevant for the problem. Could you try to build a minimal example?

Comment: @JFMeier A minimal example? I can try, but I wouldn't necessarily know how to do that. We haven't been taught anything around the liens of changing code into a minimalist state.

Comment: @JFMeier So would something along the lines of https://gist.github.com/julienhaversano/9197588 be possible? Just using this as a reference example.

Comment: I was just suggesting to write the minimal amount of code that reproduces your problem. Then describe the problems and error messages you get as detailed as possible.

Comment: I see, I get you there. I mean I don't get any error messages, the problem I'm having is that I don't understand how to interact with the converter through the URL and such.